# Solve algebraic equation with a min(a, b) term

Tags: linear-algebra, geometry, algebra-precalculus, inequality

(Please note I am not a mathematician, just a programmer trying to solve something using maths)

I have this equation:

```
1.035 x Q = min(5, 1.15 x Q)
```

Is it possible to find Q, using basic operations (no calculus etc)?

I found that min(a,b) = 1/2(a + b - |a - b|) but I am not sure how to process the modulus?

I have:

```
1.035Q = 1/2(5 + 1.15Q - | 5 - 1.15Q|)
2.07Q = 5 + 1.15Q - | 5 - 1.15Q|
0.92Q = 5 - | 5 - 1.15Q|
```

but now I am struggling.

Comment: Well, $Q$ could be $0$...that makes the equation true.  If you assume $Q\neq 0$ then, since $1.035\times Q\neq 1.15\times Q$ we must have $1.035\times Q=5$, which you can solve.  Note:  you must then check the equation, but that isn't hard.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Break it down into cases, recalling that $\min(a, b) = a$ *or* $\min(a, b) = b$.

$$1.035 \times Q = 5 \implies Q = \frac{5}{1.035} = \frac{1000}{207} \approx 4.830918$$
$$1.035 \times Q = 1.15 \times Q \implies 0 = 0.115 \times Q \implies Q = 0$$

Then plug the values back into the original equation to make sure the solutions are valid.

If $Q = 0$, then:

$$1.035 \times Q = 0$$
$$\min(5, 1.15 \times Q) = \min(5, 0) = 0$$

If $Q = \frac{1000}{207}$, then:

$$1.035 \times Q = 5$$
$$\min(5, 1.15 \times Q) = \min(5, \frac{50}{9}) = 5$$

In either case, the two sides of the equation match.  So both are valid answers.  Therefore:

$$Q \in \{0, \frac{1000}{207} \}$$

Comment: Thank you so much, didn't realise it was that simple (Q cannot be zero in my case).